# ¿Como muestro los diferentes titulos en cada label?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, split

```
btnVerCartelera.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        conexion = Conexion.conectar(); 

        try
          {
              statement = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT pelicula.nombre FROM pelicula, cine where cine.direccion=?");
              statement.setString(1, (String) cbxDireccion.getSelectedItem());
              resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

              String titulo = "";

              if(cbxDireccion.getSelectedItem() == "Forjadores")
              {
                  while(resultSet.next())
                  {
                      titulo = resultSet.getString("nombre");                           
                      lblPoster1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli1.jpg"));
                      lblPoster2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli2.jpg"));
                      lblPoster3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli3.jpg"));
                      lblPeli1.setText(titulo);
                      lblPeli2.setText(titulo);
                      lblPeli3.setText(titulo);
                  }
              }else if(cbxDireccion.getSelectedItem() == "Paseo La Paz")
              {
                  while(resultSet.next())
                  {                     
                      titulo = resultSet.getString("nombre");
                      titulo += ".";

                      String[] datos = titulo.split(".");

                      lblPoster1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli4.jpg"));
                      lblPoster2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli5.jpg"));
                      lblPoster3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli6.jpg"));
                      lblPeli1.setText("");
                      lblPeli2.setText("");
                      lblPeli3.setText("");
                  }
              }

              /*
              else
              {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No encontrado");
              }*/
              conexion.close();
          }
          catch(SQLException error)
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error en el acceso de la base de datos");
          }
```

Esa consulta me trae 3 nombres de 3 películas distintas, pero no se como ponerlos en cada uno de los 3 `labels`. Ya intente separar por `split` y meterlo en un arreglo pero me manda errores, no se si lo este haciendo mal, pero ya no se que hacer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una variable que funcione como contador y de esta forma mediante un `switch` asignar los valores a cada `label`, de esta forma:

```
      ...
      ...
 int counter = 0;

 while(resultSet.next())
 {
     titulo = resultSet.getString("nombre");                           
     lblPoster1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli1.jpg"));
     lblPoster2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli2.jpg"));
     lblPoster3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ErickDiaz\\workspace\\SistemaCine\\img\\peli3.jpg"));

            //Asigna Texto:

       switch(counter){
             case 0:
               lblPeli1.setText(titulo);
             break;
             case 1:
               lblPeli2.setText(titulo);
             break;
             case 2:
               lblPeli1.setText(titulo);
             break;
             default:
             break;

            }
            //Incrementa valor de contador.
            counter++;

 }

       ...
       ...
```